# useEffect me hace desaparecer el contenido de mi pagina

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, scss

Estoy desarrollando mi primera aplicacion con React, y me encontré con un problema con el `useEffect`.

Quiero utilizarlo para darle efectos a las letras pero cuando lo utilizo en `index.js`, me desaparece todo el contenido.

éste es index.js:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './index.scss'
import {useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AnimatedLetters from '../AnimatedLetters';
const Home = () =>{
    
    // useState hook to define the state of my class
    // as letters can only have one animateion and specific 
    // moment in time after initial loading is done.
    const [letterClass, setLetterClass] = useState('text-animate');
    const nameArray = ['j', 'u', 'a', 'n', ' ', 'i', 'g', 'n', 'a', 'c', 'i', 'o', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'a', 'v', 'i', 't', 'i', 's']
    const jobArray = ['w', 'e', 'b', ' ' , 'd', 'e', 'v', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'p', 'e', 'r',]

    useEffect(() =>{
        return setTimeout(() => {
            setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
        },4000)
    })

    return(
        <div className="container home-page"> 
            <div className="text-zone">
                <h1>
                    <span className={letterClass}>H</span>
                    <span className={`${letterClass}_12`}>i,</span>
                <br/>
                <span className={`${letterClass}_13`}>I</span>
                <span className={`${letterClass}_14`}>'m </span>
                <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass}
                    strArray={nameArray}
                    idx={15}
                />
                <br/>
                <AnimatedLetters letterClass={letterClass}
                    strArray={jobArray}
                    idx={38}
                />
                </h1>
                <h2>Junior Full Stack Developer</h2>
                <Link to="/contact" className="flat-button">CONTACT ME</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
    
    export default Home;
```

Y para el efecto me cree una carpeta donde hago las animaciones llamada **AnimatedLetters**:

```
import './index.scss'

// Receive 3 arguments:
//letterClass: The class that you want to apply to your letter
//strArray: Array of the characters 
//idx: index, starting point, set de delay

const AnimatedLetters = ({letterClass, strArray, idx}) =>{
    return(
        <span>
            {
                strArray.map((char, i) =>(
                    <span key={char + i} className={`${letterClass} _${i + idx}`}>
                        {char}
                    </span>
                ))
            }
        </span>
    );
}

export default AnimatedLetters;
```

**index.scss:**

```
.text-animate{
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
    animation: bounceIn 1s 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    min-width: 10px;
}


.text-animate-hover{
    min-width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    animation-fill-mode: both;

    &:hover{
        animation: rubberBand 1s;
        color: #ffd700;
    }
}

@for $i from 1 through 50{
    .text-animate._#{$i}{
        animation-delay: #{$i / 10}s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useEffect` no puede regresar una función del tipo `setTimeout` como *clean up function*:

```
useEffect(() =>{
    return setTimeout(() => {
            setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
        },4000)
})
```

Hay que envolver el `setTimeout` con **arrow function**, que es la función clean up:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    return () => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
          setLetterClass('text-animate-hover')
      }, 4000);
    }
  })
```

Comment: Ahora si funcionó, gracias!